# Seleccionar datos de datagridviewcomboboxcolumn y mostrar en celdas contiguas en base a la seleccion c#

Tags: c#, lista, datagrid, combobox

Tengo un pequeño problema en el cual me encuentro un poco perdido tengo un datagridviewcomboboxcolumn del cual se carga una lista y necesito que cuando escoga una de la lista se cargue automáticamente en las celdas contiguas los valores como se ve en la imagen que adjunto.

[image: DATAGRIDVIEWCOMBOBOXOCLUMN]

Este es el código que me permite llenar la columna

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn2 = dataGridPre.Columns["Tratamiento"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
        comboboxColumn2.DataSource = dao.Dentadura.Get_Tratamiento();
        comboboxColumn2.DisplayMember = "TRA_CONCEPTO";
        comboboxColumn2.ValueMember = "TRA_CONCEPTO";
```

Y aquí el código de la lista en donde están los campos que necesito pero como podría hacer para añadir en las celdas al realizar una determinada selección

```
  public static List<TratamientoEntity> Get_Tratamiento()
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT [TRA_ID],[TRA_CONCEPTO],[TRA_VALOR],[TRA_POR_DESC],[TRA_DESC],[TRA_TOTAL] FROM [TBL_TRATAMIENTO] ORDER BY TRA_ID";
        List<TratamientoEntity> list = new List<TratamientoEntity>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(Cargar_Tratamiento(reader));
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

    public static TratamientoEntity Cargar_Tratamiento(IDataReader reader)
    {
        TratamientoEntity tratamiento = new TratamientoEntity();
        tratamiento.TRA_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TRA_ID"]);
        tratamiento.TRA_CONCEPTO = Convert.ToString(reader["TRA_CONCEPTO"]);
        tratamiento.TRA_VALOR = Convert.ToDouble(reader["TRA_VALOR"]);
        tratamiento.TRA_POR_DESC = Convert.ToDouble(reader["TRA_POR_DESC"]);
        tratamiento.TRA_DESC = Convert.ToDouble(reader["TRA_DESC"]);
        tratamiento.TRA_TOTAL = Convert.ToDouble(reader["TRA_TOTAL"]);
        return tratamiento;
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjunto el codigo con lla respuesta a la pregunta.

```
 private void dataGridPre_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridPre.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Tratamiento")
        {
            //
            // se obtiene el valor seleccionado en el combo
            //
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo = dataGridPre.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

            String Tratamiento = Convert.ToString(combo.Value);

            //
            // se recupera en base al concepto del Tratamiento y se procede a buscar
            //
            dao.TratamientoEntity descuento = dao.Dentadura.Get_Tratamiento_Tra(Tratamiento);

            //
            // Se adquiere los valores para colocarlos en las celdas
            //
            DataGridViewCell valor = dataGridPre.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Valor"];
            DataGridViewCell pordes = dataGridPre.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PorDesc"];
            DataGridViewCell des = dataGridPre.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Dsctos"];
            DataGridViewCell total = dataGridPre.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"];

            valor.Value = descuento.TRA_VALOR;
            pordes.Value = descuento.TRA_POR_DESC;
            des.Value = descuento.TRA_DESC;
            total.Value = descuento.TRA_TOTAL;
        }
    }
```